# IOCTL from kernel space

Tags: random, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, ioctl

Roughly speaking, I am trying to issue an IOCTL call from kernel space without going to user space. (All the answers I found in SO propose going through user space).

Specifically, I try to fill the entropy pool (`/dev/random`) from kernel space (using a kernel module) [I know the dangers of doing this ;)]. Filling up the entropy pool from user space is done using IOCTL, e.g., [rngaddentropy](https://github.com/rfinnie/twuewand/blob/master/rndaddentropy/rndaddentropy.c). Is there a way to do the same thing from kernel space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ioctl from the kernel space too.

Because ioctl command `RNDADDENTROPY` is file-specific, its processing should be implemented in the `.unlocked_ioctl` operation for `/dev/random` file (and it is actually implemented this way, see function [random_ioctl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c#L1527)).

For file-specific ioctl commands you may call `.unlocked_ioctl` file's operation directly:

```c
// Open file
struct file* f = filp_open("/dev/random", O_WRONLY, 0);
// Replace user space with kernel space
mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

f->f_op->unlocked_ioctl(f, RNDADDENTROPY, entropy);

// Restore space
set_fs(old_fs);

// Close file
filp_close(f, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Out of curiosity: What happens if "/dev/random" under a different file name? Is there a way to bypass the `ioctl` call and add data to entropy pool? I checked `random.c` but the function `write_pool` is not exported.

Comment: There are some exported functions from that file, like [add_device_randomness](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c#L759). Probably you will find some of them usefull for your purposes. As for `write_pool`, it is called indirectly when writting into the file.